# Левый операнд с другим оператором присваивания

Tags: javascript

Можно более яркий пример на этот пример, объяснить почему так, либо ссылку, где этот случай был бы описан более подробно?!

```
a[i++] += 5         // i оценивается только один раз
a[i++] = a[i++] + 5 // i оценивается дважды
```

Comment: что значит "оценивается"?

Comment: Это из MDN.... Там написано про это следующее... В необычных ситуациях оператор присваивания, например, x += y не идентичен выражению, x = x + y. Когда левый операнд оператора присваивания содержит оператор присваивания, левый операнд оценивается только один раз. Например:

Comment: Все, разобрался, создал массив, прошелся по их индексам в цикле, применил в цикле оба варианта, понял суть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все довольно просто: понимайте эти записи буквально. В первом случае  `i++` встречается 1 раз, во втором 2. Поэтому и поведение соответствующее.

Если более детально, то запись `a[i++] += 5`, это не то же самое, что и `a[i++] = a[i++] + 5`. Мы ведь можем записать вот так

```
i++
a[i] += 5 // a[i] = a[i] + 5
```

Так же примерно и движок `js` делает

P.S. 
`a[i++] = a[i++] + 5` так писать нельзя, потому что вы получите не совсем то что ожидаете. Например, если `i = 0`, то в первом `a[i++]` возьмется элемент с индексом `0`, потому что присваивание идет после получения значения, а во втором `a[i++]` мы уже будем иметь индекс `1`, то есть `a[0] = a[1] + 5`